# Noncommutative Localization "from scratch"

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

In his excellent monograph "Lectures on Modules and Rings" (GTM 189), T.Y. Lam remarks (10.13), p. 302, that there is no direct method of computing the kernel of the (co-)unit of the adjunction when localizing a ring $R$ w.r.t. a right denominator set $S$. My question then: Is there really no way of identifying $\text{ker}\,\varepsilon$ "from scratch", i.e. as $\lbrace r\in R \;:\; rs=0$ for some $s\in S\rbrace$, just from the desired universal property (but still assuming that $S$ is a right denominator set) ? Any help/insightful comments would be dearly appreciated !

Kind regards and thank you in advance, St.

Comment: I've asked the same question in the commutative setting here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/86923

Comment: @Martin: the commutative setting is really different!!! The common point of view for localizing a module $M$ on a commutative ring $R$ with respect to a multiplicative subset $\Sigma\subseteq R$ is to view the elements of $\Sigma$ as endomorphisms of $M$ and so take the direct limit of $|\Sigma|$-many copies of $M$ with these transition maps. When $R$ is not commutative you cannot do so if $\Sigma$ is not included in the center $Z(\Sigma)$. This is a non-trivial complication (in concrete situations it makes really a lot of difference, I can give you concrete examples)!  